# Apache Subdomain (Raspberry Pi B+)

Tags: apache, dns, subdomain, raspbian

I have create an **apache** server on my Raspberry Pi B+ (Raspbian) and I use DNS (selenuix.servehttp.com). I want to create two subdomain : for french users (fr.selenuix.servehttp.com) and for english users (en.selenuix.servehttp.com). How can I do this ? Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Need read a lot system setting manuals if you a newbie.Ex: `man a2ensite` etc.

Comment: But I want know how to create a subdomain without reading conf